# problems to have bokeh gridplots with same size

Tags: python, bokeh

I managed to use `gridplot` to show multiple axes in Bokeh. But after the colorbar and label were added, plots did not have same size. some of them were narrow. I want them to have same size one another. I am not sure if it is due to the labels and colorbars.

[image: Image of plot with different subplot widths.]

```py
for comp in idxComps: #adding labels
       if comp % numCols == 0:
            fig[comp].yaxis.axis_label = axLabel[1]
        if comp >= (numRows-1) * numCols:
            fig[comp].xaxis.axis_label = axLabel[0]

fig[comp].image(image=[values[..., comp].transpose()],
                      x=lower[0], y=lower[1],
                      dw=(upper[0]-lower[0]), dh=(upper[1]-lower[1]),
                      palette="Inferno256")
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette='Inferno256',
                           low=np.amin(values[...,comp]), 
                           high=np.amax(values[...,comp]))
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, 
                     width=7, 
                     location=(0,0), 
                     formatter=BasicTickFormatter(precision=1), 
                     ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=4), 
                     label_standoff=12, 
                     border_line_color=None) #adding a color bar

fig[comp].add_layout(color_bar, 'right')


gridplot(children=fig, toolbar_location=None, ncols=numCols, sizing_mode="scale_height", merge_tools=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of Bokeh (1.1 or later) you can explicitly pass `frame_width` and `frame_height` values to `figure` to control the dimension of the "inner" plot area.